# Can we get rid of stackoverflow.uservoice.com completely?

Tags: discussion, uservoice

The junk posts on the site have now been cleaned up, and it's been closed to prevent anyone posting new content. The current situation is that it will remain as a historical artifact.

---

I was just googling something about Stack Overflow, and I somehow ended up on [uservoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20111119235718/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/1722-general). Looking at that page, it doesn't exactly give a very good impression of Stack Overflow. Wouldn't it be a good idea to take it down?

**Update:** for those who still think that it shouldn't be killed with fire, take a look at the "top" questions on the [homepage](https://web.archive.org/web/20111119235718/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/1722-general).

**Update 2:** If possible, a 301 to meta could be nice?

Comment: LOLOLOL PROGRAMMING ROFL

Comment: @lunboks exactly :D

Comment: The title of this post made me think you wanted to get rid of meta--where all the users have a well heard voice. And ponies.

Comment: @Manishearth god not the ponies. corrected.

Comment: Oof. I was going to suggest leaving it alone for historical purposes... and then I clicked the link. Kill it with fire.

Comment: The posts that have been vomited on the front page since the site was made obsolete are spam, yeah, [but the posts that ended up being declined are still up there](https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/status/10395) and they're somewhat interesting.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle - maybe they can keep a data dump or something - it's just that I don't think that the content on there should be representing stack overflow.

Comment: Browsing through the declined feature requests, I don't see anything particularly interesting there. There's certainly no *new* information/justifications that haven't already been repeated *ad nauseum* here on Meta. Why keep it?

Comment: It's growing weeds. It needs to go away. I'm rather sad to say that, but it needs to go away.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Do you still have mod powers on UserVoice? Can you clean it up one _last_ time?

Comment: @TimPost I assume "go away" is shorthand for "be locked for historical significance, and forever preserved as a gem of our history"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I was actually alluding to the button most people use when emptying a toilet (or water closet, depending on where you live). Unless it's going to be curated, it doesn't need to become a piece in a museum :)

Comment: The 4th top idea is slightly strange...

Comment: @CoffeeRain you mean the 4th top comment? If so, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/166294) may help.

Comment: @CoffeeRain exactly.. a great example of why it needs to go

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yeah, that's a bit untidy...

But, I can't actually find anyone here with a working login! Obviously, the site hasn't been used in a few years...

I've emailed UV's support desk, we'll see what they can do.

---

Ok, Claire over at UV helped me get admin access - I've removed the trash and closed the forum to new posts. What's there can stand as a historical artifact unless / until we decide to remove it entirely.

Thanks for bringing this up, Alex!

Comment: Man, that's like boarding NCC-1701 from NCC-1701[letter] and finding out that life support can't be repaired and the warp core is about to explode. There's no other choice than to warp out and launch aft photon torpedoes as we go, or those pesky Romulans will keep trolling. Survivors have been safely beamed aboard.

Comment: Yes, it's *exactly* like... wait, what?

Comment: I'm surprised they don't have meta.uservoice.com or uservoice.uservoice.com...

Comment: Heh, uservoice.uservoice.com actually *did* exist at one time, I remember posting suggestions there, @Alex. Now it redirects to feedback.

Comment: No one will know it's a historical artefact unless you have another site talk about the gold in them thar hills. Or tiny text banners on each of the requests

Comment: [tag:status-completed] then?

Comment: Eh, not really @Hod... I mean, it's still *there*

Comment: Thanks @Shog9 - that's great - it's probably best for it to still exist now that the junk stuff has gone and it's closed.