# What happened to stackoverflow.uservoice.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history, uservoice

What happened to [stackoverflow.uservoice.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219112537/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/)
and why was the site removed or discontinued? Because I was looking at some old questions here and I found out that there was a stackoverflow.uservoice.com.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should meta.stackoverflow.com replace uservoice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com)

Comment: @bobble no, it doesn't fully explain what's going to happen. (I also  found this one and considered closing)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What happened, is that it was superseded by Meta Stack Overflow (later Meta Stack Exchange). Why use other software to host discussions about the community, the network, and the software powering it if your own software is capable of hosting it as well?

Some relevant links mentioned by @ShadowWizard in the comments:

- [Should meta.stackoverflow.com replace uservoice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com)
- [Can we get rid of stackoverflow.uservoice.com completely?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127887/can-we-get-rid-of-stackoverflow-uservoice-com-completely)

If you want to know how the site looked like, you can also browse [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/*).

Comment: What year did Meta overtake uservoice? When I read the question it sounded like the change was recent `why is the site removed`

Comment: @Mari-LouA The body of the question indicates that the OP only _found out about it_ recently: _"Because I was looking at some old questions here and I found out that there was a stackoverflow.uservoice.com"_.